# Setting regionName on Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework, region

I am trying to add an event to a button in Javascript. I m using a framework that is belong to my company that I am working and after clicking the button I need to set a region name to a region. The problem is that the first time when I click to button region name is not setted. When I tried for the second time it is setted and it works one step back..

Basically it looks :

```
region.setRegionName(regionName);
```

when I debug this region name is not empty string. But after few lines later when I wanted to show name of region by

```
region.getRegionName()
```

the response is empty. (about blank). But for the second try, it works. But for sure it is working one step from back. I mean that first I choose to set region name "x" by the first try and it responses empty. After I choose "y" as region name, and after setting region name, when I call `getRegionName` it returns "x".

The parameters is right when I am setting I debug these kind of things. So what can be the problem?

Comment: can you post the code where you bind the handler to the click event, as well as the entire function that `region.setRegionName(regionName);` and `region.getRegionName()` live in?

Comment: What's that Java-ee tag doing here?